# Trouble Using Swift NSDate "timeIntervalSinceNow"

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I've searched around and am flummoxed by this riddle.

In Swift, Xcode 6.2, these lines work:

```
let day_seconds = 86400
let one_day_from_now = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:86400)
```

But the following returns an error:

```
let day_seconds = 86400
let one_day_from_now = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:day_seconds)
```

Console output:

> "Playground execution failed: /var/folders/4n/88gryr0j2pn318sw_g_mgkgh0000gn/T/lldb/10688/playground625.swift:24:30: error: extra argument 'timeIntervalSinceNow' in call
>   let one_day_from_now = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:day_seconds)"

What's going on here? Why the NSDate trickiness?

Comment: It isn't NSDate trickiness. It is Swift numerics trickiness... :(

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't assume that one day has 86400 seconds (think of daylight saving time transitions). Better use NSCalendar methods for all calendrical calculations.

Answer (score 6):

It's because `timeIntervalSinceNow` expect `NSTimeInterval` which is `Double`.

If you do:

```
let day_seconds = 86400
```

day_second is Int  type which is not what the method expect.
However when you type the number itself:

```
let one_day_from_now = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:86400)
```

compiler implicit that you are passing Double, because it's what the method expect, which is ok.

The solution cancould be using 
`NSTimeInterval(day_seconds)` or `Double(day_seconds)` which is the same or when you declare constant make sure it's double, for example:

```
let day_seconds = 86400.0
```

or

```
let day_seconds: Double = 86400
```

or

```
let day_seconds: NSTimeInterval = 86400
```

Comment: Verbose but correct. :)

Comment: Thank you, Greg, for the very clear explanation. I now have an understanding of Swift numerics trickiness. I apologize for the duplicate question, Matt!